# MongoDB and Mongoose Abnormal behavior?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, redis, mongoose-schema

I apologize for the maybe trivial question. I am accessing mongo db to obtain information on a user, verify the password, and save some data in Redis if the validation was successful.
But I'm misbehaving (probably my mistake).

My simple backend is built in express 4.17.2, node 17.2.0, and redis4.0.1.
Server-side MongoDB on cloud MongoDB Atlas (Version 4.4.10) and RedisLab (Redis in cloud version 6.2.3).

Here are some code snippets:

```
app.post('/identity/login', (req, res) => {
let userHash = '';
let result = false;
const user = req.body;
userHash = crud.login(user.username);
userHash.then(h => {
    result = bcrypt.compareSync(user.password, h.password);
    console.log('All object ',h);
    console.log('Access to roles array',h.roles);
    let value = {name:h.name, surname:h.surname,  roles:h.roles, username:h.username};
    console.log('value', value);
    client.set(h.password, JSON.stringify(value), { EX: 60, NX: true });
   
    res.send(result);
});
```

});

Making the POST call to that endpoint, I get the following (unexpected) results, highlighted by the logs:

```
All object  {
  _id: new ObjectId("61d1d38d0f4bac12d8f504ee"),
  username: 'jdoe',
  password: '$2a$14$5GULZRmiN0DXQXMaLwQiEO9S/OlBll5U4ZwkBn2NYpju0VRDFUqVO',
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Doe',
  roles: [ 'Admin' ]
}
Access to roles array undefined
value { name: 'John', surname: 'Doe', roles: undefined, username: 'jdoe' }
```

As you can see, if I log h.roles I get that the array is not defined, while logging the whole object the array property 'roles' is correctly valued. So obviously, when I go to build the object to save in Redis (as h.roles), the array is not created.

Why? Could you please help me and say me what I am doing wrong? My mistake, a mongoose problem (see 6.4.1)?

Below, I show the code to access MongoDB:

```
const login = async (username) => {
    connectDB();
    let dbPwd;
    const User = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
    return await User.findOne({ username: username }, 'password name surname roles username').exec();
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Does `crud.login` return a simple object, or something a little more complex?

Comment: Hello @Joe,
crud.login returns the object in the MongoDB users collection, as seen in the code snippet above. In findOne, I only indicated which properties to return.
Thank you

Comment: How is that defined in the schema?

Comment: Hi @Joe, this is my definition schema: const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ username: String, password: String, name: String, surname: String, roles: Array });